# Meaning of /sys/fs/cgroup

Tags: linux, cgroup

While reading the Linux documentation on cgroups I have found some things to be a bit unclear:

1. I noticed that (in the examples) the root of all cgroups is always /sys/fs/cgroup/. Is there any special meanings to this directory? Or can I also do

   `mount -t tmpfs cgroup_root /some/other/cgroup/root/`?
2. Is there a special reason why the tmpfs file system is used?